# Unable to Rotate Display

Tags: pi-3b+, display, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I recently purchased an 8.8in display from AliExpress (8.8inch IPS HSD088IPW1 Long strip display Stretched Bar HDMI compatible Display Aida64 monitor USB 5V Power Second Display Case)
(https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2255800212199308.html?spm=a2g0o.order_detail.0.0.3b08f19cYBiazn&gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt)

and found a semi-successful way to get it to display on a WaveShare website (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/8.8inch_Side_Monitor#Work_with_Raspberry_Pi) by putting the below in the config.txt:

```
max_framebuffer_height=1920
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_force_mode=1
hdmi_timings=480 0 30 30 30 1920 0 18 6 6 0 0 0 60 0 66280000 3
gpu_mem=512 #Pi Zero series please change to gpu_mem=256
```

Now I want to rotate the display from portrait to landscape but `display_rotate=1` doesn't work, nor does `display_hdmi_rotate=1`, `display_lcd_rotate=1` or `lcd_rotate=1`. I've also attempted adding the three display rotate entries and flipping the `hdmi_timings=` values.

Raspberry Pi 3 B+ using Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye (Lite)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in a Reddit thread, turns out I had to comment out `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d`

Thanks to the user jdpg265 on this thread:
https://www.reddit.com/r/octoprint/comments/if65es/unable_to_rotate_7inch_raspberry_pi_touch_screen/

ultimate config file entries look like this after commenting out the above:

```
max_framebuffer_width=480
max_framebuffer_height=1920
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_force_mode=1
hdmi_timings=480 0 30 30 30 1920 0 18 6 6 0 0 0 60 0 66280000 3
gpu_mem=256
display_rotate=1
```

Comment: Same here. Had to comment out dtoverlay on a RasPi Zero W 1.1. After that, rotating hdmi worked.